# Reverse a linked list using only 2 pointers using XOR operation

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, xor

I found this code online for reversing a linked list using only 2 pointers using xor operation :

```
void reverse(struct Node** head_ref) 
{ 
    struct Node* prev = NULL; 
    struct Node* current = *head_ref; 

    // at last prev points to new head 
    while (current != NULL) { 
        current = (struct Node*)((ut)prev ^ (ut)current ^ (ut)(current->next) ^ (ut)(current->next = prev) ^ (ut)(prev = current)); 
    } 

    *head_ref = prev; 
}
```

Can you please explain how this code works ?

Comment: What is ut?  Does it work on a 64-bit system or only on a 32-bit system?

Comment: typedef uintptr_t ut;

Comment: This looks more like C to me.

Comment: It is C++ because they had included 
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std;

Comment: Who teaches introducing such nonsensical `typedef`s...

Comment: That has undefined behaviour due to the unsequenced pairs `prev`/`prev = current`, and `current->next`/`current->next = prev`. geeksforgeeks is not a reliable source of knowledge.

Comment: *they had included <bits/stdc++.h>* then you can probably safely ignore them and everything they write.

Comment: I have heard this is not C++ compliant. Why is including this header file considered a bad practice?

Comment: Can you please explain how we are not losing the list after current=current->next when we use xor ? This is the main reason why we use 3 pointers. How is this done without another pointer by using xor ? @molbdnilo

Comment: There's nothing to explain. As I said earlier, that code has undefined behaviour, so anything can happen. Don't try to learn from geeksforgeeks, it's not good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you read this: [Iteratively Reverse a linked list using only 2 pointers](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iteratively-reverse-a-linked-list-using-only-2-pointers/)?

```
   while (current != NULL) { 
        // This expression evaluates from left to right 
        // current->next = prev, changes the link fron 
        // next to prev node 
        // prev = current, moves prev to current node for 
        // next reversal of node 
        // This example of list will clear it more 1->2->3->4 
        // initially prev = 1, current = 2 
        // Final expression will be current = 1^2^3^2^1, 
        // as we know that bitwise XOR of two same 
        // numbers will always be 0 i.e; 1^1 = 2^2 = 0 
        // After the evaluation of expression current = 3 that 
        // means it has been moved by one node from its 
        // previous position 
        current = (struct Node*)((ut)prev ^ (ut)current ^ (ut)(current->next) ^ (ut)(current->next = prev) ^ (ut)(prev = current)); 
    }
```

Comment: Yes, but I have trouble understanding that. How is prev 1 and current = 2?

Comment: It means the previous node has 1 as value  and the current one is 2, they have ascending order. This is the key: `(ut)(current->next = prev) ^ (ut)(prev = current)`, is storing addresses (`uintptr_t` is an integer type capable of holding a pointer) in a temporary using xor operations while assigning the previous node (stored in the previous iteration). Is obfuscated code and add nothing to the conventional way of doing it: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reverse-a-linked-list/?ref=rp

Comment: Initially prev is NULL and current is pointing to head node which is 1. How does prev node have 1 and current node have 2 ? I still did not get it.

Comment: The first iteration swaps the address of `NULL` (0) with the address of the first node: `0 ^ 1` (xoring any value with `0` is a NOOP), then `1 ^ 2`, then `2 ^ 3` and so on ...

Comment: How is the address of the 1st node (current) 1? It's data is only 1 right?

Comment: Yes, `^` is swapping addresses not values

Comment: So, will any pointer pointing to the head node (1st node) give an address of 1 after casting the pointer with (ut) ? Is that how  uintptr_t works? Sorry, for asking too many questions

Comment: Does the swapping take place first, or does current pointer(in the LHS) move to the next node first?

Comment: See the comment of @Molbdnilo: _That has undefined behaviour due to the unsequenced pairs prev/prev = current, and current->next/current->next = prev_ this is UB, you can not tell the order, do not use this code.

Comment: Thank you ! Then, does that mean reversing linked list with 2 pointers is not possible (other than this code using xor) ?

Comment: No, this code is not well defined, as I said it invokes UB, this is very well explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points